# Translation using django trans tag

Tags: django

In django templates i have a tag as `{% trans mypage %}`
And in translation pages i have `en/django.po` files i have mypage pointing to "`mypage`"

My question is if i have to change `mypage` to `minepage` then should i change it in views or `django.po` file

As i understand mypage is only a variable ,to change to appropriate translation we have to change it in `.po` file and makemessage and compile message. Am i right?

Comment: I would recommend you using an application like django-rosetta, which helps you a lot managing those files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You define translatable strings in your templates and python classes, then you use django commands: `makemessages` (which makes/updates .PO files) + `compilemessages` (which makes/updates .MO). So, the point is: you should edit .PO files manually only to change the translation of your label (its value).